# Running SPARK job with local Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am submitting a spark job as follows :

```
spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=5051 server_code.py
```

My python is set to my home users python :

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="$HOME/software/anaconda3/bin/python3.7"
```

However when I run spark like this it cannot access this python so complains. Is there any way around this? I am able to run spark jobs with the above configurations when the job doesnt involve a web UI. In the case above, I am serving out a web UI with the results.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/x/software/anaconda3/bin/python3.7": error=13, Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have the perms to create folders inside HDFS?

Comment: If you have a Spark cluster of multiple machines, then one variable on only one machine with that version of Python, won't work out so well when the code runs on a different machine without Anaconda

Comment: @cricket_007 am not entirely sure but i have run spark submit jobs with the same pyspark_python location for a job that simply used some MLlib function and printed out to console. In the case above I am trying to then serve this out as a website and here is when the problem exists

Comment: @Prazy: Yes i have permission to create folders inside HDFS.

Comment: My point is that Spark is designed to run on multiple machines. One out of many machines could be giving that error

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. So what should my pyspark_python variable point to?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. Permission denied can be solved using '**chmod**'
chmod u+x /software/anaconda3/bin/python3.7

Comment: First of all, you haven't even specified that you actually have more than one machine, so if you don't then forget about it. If you want to fix the problem, perhaps you can try running your code in `pyspark` shell first?

Comment: @cricket_007 : I have four machines. I've logged into each of these to check if they have access to the folder and they do. I've modified the folder to  have access to the python for pyspark and set environment variables. Even this is throwing the same error

Comment: This is how we do it: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/pyspark-anaconda-quot-permission-denied-quot/td-p/44131

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by providing access permissions to folders from the home directory. chmod 777 dir name all the way down to chmod 777 to the actual python script